# Make image as background into an empty row in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would place an image into a row by using backstretch jquery plugin. Here is it a snippet:

```
  script
    $("#img-background").backstretch("/image.jpg");

  .container-fluid
    .row
      #img-background
```

Nothing has to be placed into row just a background image through the above plugin but unfortunately the image is not showed since the row is empty.Beside I would get an image responsive. The width image is 1050px. If i use `background-size: cover` unfortuntately the image is not responsive. Any suggest to get an image responsive?

**EXAMPLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/wcqx8esx/

Comment: please add jsfidle with your code

Comment: To make the width of the image responsive use `max-width:800px; height:auto;` -- any width value you like.

Comment: Ok here is an example

Comment: You are using a `#` which indicates an `id`, but `img-background` is a class, use a `.`